# duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, dependencies

I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:    android/support/annotation/ColorRes.class
```

What I am doing?

1-multiDexEnabled

2-add this: configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' } and no work (another duplicate entry error)

3-Delete dependencies one by one. doesn't work or get another error

4-exclude dependencies one by one and doesn't work

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPljg.jpg)

**What could be the problem?**

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


   dependencies
    {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
        compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.4@aar'
        compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.1'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
        compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
        compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile files('libs/appodeal-1.13.10.jar')
        compile files('libs/applovin-6.1.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/inmobi-5.0.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/my-target-4.1.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/yandex-metrica-android-2.00.jar')
    }

 android
 {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


defaultConfig
{
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode VERSION_MAJOR*10000000 + VERSION_MINOR*100000 +      VERSION_PATCH*1000 + VERSION_BUILD
    versionName "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't say for sure, but my guess is it's related to using multiple different version numbers in the support libraries,

Comment: @Brucelet Thanks, change all of them to 22 but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that you've got multiple dependencies either implementing the same class, or referencing different versions (in different packages) of the same class.

The former might be happening because you're including the support library both from maven:
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'`
and from your local filesystem: `compile files('libs/android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar')`. I'd recommend removing the local dependency.

The latter can happen if you mix different Android support dependency versions. In your case you are mixing an older version of CardView and RecyclerView with newer root support libraries:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'`

Try making all of your com.android.support dependencies reference build 22.2.1.

Putting that all together, **delete your project's local file `libs/android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar`** and try this as your Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies
    {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
        compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.4@aar'
        compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.1'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
        compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
        compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile files('libs/appodeal-1.13.10.jar')
        compile files('libs/applovin-6.1.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/inmobi-5.0.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/my-target-4.1.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/yandex-metrica-android-2.00.jar')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, when I delete android-support-v4-22.2.1.jar I get several errors like this: Error:(19, 31) error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist

Comment: It looks like you're excluding that from your build.

Comment: Try removing this: `configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need support-annotations package, you can exclude it in your `build.gradle` app:

```
android{
    ...
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```